# How to create new POST request with Parameters in Laravel 5.5 from INSIDE Controller Method

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to call my own laravel api with POST method but I am not getting the post values in get_cities_list method.

**LocationController.php**

```
public function get_cities(){
$params = array('country_id' => 1);
$req = Request::create('api/get_cities_list', 'POST', $params);
$response = json_decode(Route::dispatch($req)->getCOntent());
print_r($response);
}
```

**Api/CommonController.php**

```
public function get_cities_list(Request $request){
print_r($request->all()) //empty array
print_r($_POST) //empty array
}
```

Comment: use http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ to send requests

Comment: I am using $this->call('POST', '/api/get_cities_list', ['country' => 1]); is it correct to use call method or should I use guzzle for sending request?

Answer (score 0):

Use guzzle for sending request with php.

You could also use vue to set it up. Or ajax calls.

Could you provide your web.php?

Comment: I am using $this->call('POST', '/api/get_cities_list', ['country' => 1]); is it correct to use call method or should I use guzzle for sending request?